# What happens to those who have not completed their conversion post to the coming of moshiach?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, conversion-to-judaism, masechet-yevamot, ymoth-hamoshiach

Given that moshiach can come at any time, what will happen to those that are in the process of conversion? 
Certain passages such as yevamos 24b, geirus would no longer be performed in the messianic era. At the same time there were general limitation on geirus lest people try to join the Jewish people for motives other than wanting to serve Hashem. (such as financial growth or some sort of benefits)... However, Yisro who already had stature and wealth was allowed given that he had "good intentions" and no ulterior motive.

An opinion I read before, source which to my shame have forgotten, stated that ultimately all the world would become Israel. This is a beautiful thought but it's debatable given the prophecies of nations coming to celebrate sukkos.

I think there might be geiros available, post the coming of moshiach, for those truly in love with the Torah and Hashem. I guess we'd all have to live it and see what happens. 
A convert is compared to a deer among sheep in the Midrash, these people leave families and lives behind just in an effort to be counted among the Jewish people. I don't think such a person would ever be set aside by Hashem. I like to think they would be allowed to finish their geirus. I was hoping for some citations or baraitot to support my thought but your comments help more than you think. Thanks.

Comment: "ultimately all the world would become Israel" is referring to the borders of the land of Israel (that ultimately then entire earth will have the halachic status of 'Eretz Yisroel'), not converts. Gentiles are an essential part of the world as they are, not as Jews The complete revelation of G-d's Kingship in the world requires both Jews and gentiles.

Answer (score 1):

The *Galus* - exile - cannot be ended until all the *Geirim* convert as the Gemara Pesachim 87b says explained by Yaaros Dvash (r'Yonasan Eibeshitz) 8,16:

> דע כי אמרו (פסחים פז ע"ב) לא גלו ישראל לבין האומות אלא כדי שיתוספו עליהם גרים כי בכל מקום שהם מתלקטים להם גרים **וכאשר יהיו נלקטים הגרים הראוים לבית יעקב והנלוים עמם אז תהיה הגאולה** כי זוהי תכלית הגלות ללקט הנפזרים והנדחים בארבע כנפות ארץ הם נשמות גרים שהם בין האומות ועל ידי גלות ישראל מתדבקים עמם ונלוים להם
>
> Know that *Chazal* (our Rabbis) said we were only exiled in order for converts to join us from within the nations, because wherever we gather in exile converts join us and **when the genuine** (i.e not for ulterior motive) **converts join the houe of Jacob *then* the redemption will come**, because this was the purpose of exile to foreign lands, in order gather the scatterred souls from the Nations of the earth from all four corners of the earth

Comment: Based on your quote from R' Yonasan Eibeshitz, those who haven't fully converted before the coming of Mashiach, would NOT be allowed to complete their conversion. (Perhaps you should edit your answer to reflect that). Remember, according to RYE, when all the legitimate converts join the house of Jacob, that’s when the redemption will come. Meaning; that the redemption is being held up until all these people convert. By inference, once the redemption has in fact come, that signals to us, that anyone not having converted yet, was not part of the necessary equation.

Answer (score 1):

Yemos hamashiach means the Era of mashiach which does not start till all the wars of Gog umagog are complete. So that could be a long period of time which will shake out any fake converts who just want to join the Jewish people when things are good.So if this convert held on he or she will be accepted we just don't want people joining after everything is clear that the jews are the chosen nation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).